# add new array to object js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i am trying to when user click the button add new array in object with new values. i want something like this.

html:

```
<input type="text"></input>
<button></button>
```

js:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',function(){
let inputValue = document.queryselector('input').value;
 let obj = {
   [ inputValue]
  }
});
```

and when second click happened  user get new input value i want something like this:

js:

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',function(){
let inputValue = document.queryselector('input').value;
 let obj = {
   [ inputValue],
   [ second inputValue]
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to push another array with only 1 value to the object every time? Simply pushing the values to one array in the object would make it a lot easier.

Comment: yeah i want just this

Comment: The way you showed the object in your question doesn't work tho. It's not valid JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let obj = [];
$('#button-id').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  let inputValue = $('#input-id').val();
  let array = [];
  array.push(inputValue)
  obj.push(array);
  console.log(obj);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id='input-id'>
<button id="button-id">Add</button>
```